# EntityManager cannot perform updates within data layer object called from within a jUnit test

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test, entitymanager

We have a Java EE application that runs within Apache Tomcat. It uses EJB 3.0 along with Spring framework.

The Entity Manager is injected within a DBL object as such:

```
public abstract class DBL extends LogBL {

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collasped" desc="Properties">
    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    protected DataSource dataSource;

    @PersistenceContext()
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier("transactionTemplate")
    protected TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
```

From there, our business layer objects will extend DBL so that they inherit the entity manager.

This all works within our Apache Tomcat system. However, we have an issue that I need to debug which I cannot tell if it's a data issue in the database, or a logic flaw in the code, so I want to run the business logic locally within Netbeans via jUnit so I can debug and trace the code interactively.

We have a section of code that does the following:

```
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT r.src_system_name, " + "                r.src_pt_name, "
                + "                r.src_flow_name, " + "                r.ivl_length_ddl_val, "
                + "                r.ivl_precision_ddl_val, " + "                r.ivl_type_ddl_val "
                + "    FROM raw_interval r " + "   WHERE r.processed_flag='N' "
                + "     AND r.mod_date < systimestamp - " + DAYS + " " + "ORDER BY r.src_system_name ");
        List<Object[]> lo = q.getResultList();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String currentSrcId = "";
```

This all works fine.

We check to see if the **lo** object has any data returned, and if so, it will then go an execute an update statement to update the records. The code to do so is as follows:

```
            Query qU = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE raw_interval r " + "   SET r.processed_flag = 'F' "
                    + " WHERE r.processed_flag='N' " + "   AND r.mod_date < systimestamp - " + DAYS + " ");
            qU.executeUpdate();
```

This all works, as I stated, when running in Apache Tomcat.

The problem is, when I do it in a jUnit test case, the first select statement works, but as soon as it tries to do the update right after, it throws an error stating:

> e = (corebuslogic.common.exceptions.LoggedException) corebuslogic.common.exceptions.LoggedException: Cannot call methods requiring a transaction if the entity manager has not been joined to the current transaction.

Here is the jUnit test case. Also, the spring-text.xml sets up JTA as the transaction manager which is fine for when it runs in our Tomcat instance. But here, the original developers apparently set up the transaction for the jUnit tests to still use JTA which I think is possibly the issue when trying to run this locally in Netbeans via a jUnit test case. I'm still learning about Spring, etc but this is an application that was dropped in my lap after it went live. I was never a part of the development of the application.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(inheritLocations = true, locations = "classpath:spring/spring-test.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class ProcessRawBLTest {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(ProcessRawBL.BEAN_NAME)
  private ProcessRawBL processRawBL;
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(LookupBL.BEAN_NAME)
  private LookupBL lookupBL;

  @Test
  @Transactional
  public void testProcessRawMV90Actual() {
    int sizeThreadPool = 1;
    Config processRawThreadsConfig = lookupBL.findConfigByNamespace(CONFIG.ProcessRaw_Threads.value);
    if (processRawThreadsConfig != null) {
      sizeThreadPool = Integer.parseInt(processRawThreadsConfig.getConfigVal());
    }

    String[] srcArray = new String[] { "MV90 Actual" };
    List<String> sources = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String source : srcArray) {
      sources.add(source);
    }
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    try {
      processRawBL.processRaw(sources, sizeThreadPool, result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

The call into the processRawBL.processRaw() function will eventually access the injected EntityManager and as I stated, it works fine as long as we're just selecting data.

But once we need a transaction for updates, then it won't work and throws the exception.

It can read the database, but we just can't write to it when trying to run the code locally and not within the Apache Tomcat container.

Hopefully that gives enough information. I've had some people at work say that mixing jUnit with the non Springboot Spring framework can get a little quirky, but I wasn't sure if that was true or not.